# Transmission "downloading 0 from 0 peers"

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

I really don't download bitorrents but there's one I really wanted. I got to 44.5% before it stalled.

The torrent page claims "Seeds 55, Peers 31" but when I view Transmission/Properties/Trackers, I see "got a list of 1 peers 2 minutes ago" and five "could not connect to tracker".

Is there anything I can realistically do to complete this?

Comment: Have you forwarded a port for incoming connections?

Comment: Torrent sites' "stats" are almost always either out of date or just outright made up.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that you change torrent.

From how you describe the problem, to me it seems that none of the peers you can connect to have the whole 100% file.

You can check it via right click > Properties > Nodes and order them by percentage, like in this picture

[image]